# Error: Unable to locate the model you have specified: discount_model on Cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob

I'm running EE v2.9.2 and Cartthrob 2.61

The store processes the order and send the notification, on return, I receive the following error:

**"Unable to locate the model you have specified: discount_model"**

Any help & insight is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the meantime, i commented out the following lines at third_party/cartthrob/drivers/core/Cartthrob_core_ee.php and it did the trick. We don't use discounts anyway :)

```
//formerly process_coupon_codes
public function process_discounts()
{
/*
    $this->EE->load->model('discount_model');

    $this->EE->load->model('coupon_code_model');

    $this->EE->discount_model->process_discounts();

    $this->EE->coupon_code_model->process_coupon_codes();
*/
```

Hoping someong can provide a better solution, but this will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this, but it's "COUPON_CODE_MODEL" that can't be found in my install.  I'm on the same versions of EE & CT.

This is happening when I try to check out with Offline Payments, when I have set "When order is taken, set processing status to:" to "Complete", rather than "Processing".  When "Processing" it submits fine; when "Complete", I get the error message.